# Systemverilog: Is there any way to pass in a module name into a module?

Tags: module, system-verilog

Is there any way to pass in something that can be used for a module name (for a submodule) into a module? Does verilog consider the module name to be a special entity, that cant be a type or string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module names are not parameterizable like data types. However, SystemVerilog has a configuration mechanism that allows you to choose which module definitions are bound to which module instantiations. See Section 33 of the 1800-2012 LRM.

Comment: Wow that's confusing on first glance. Going to have to read the whole section. Do you know if the current version of VCS/DC support this?

Comment: Where does the config block go? In all these examples I don't see it anywhere? Is it inside the top module?

Comment: It's a separate block, usually in a separate file.